# Load Json variables (Razor no MVC)

Tags: json, razor

I need your help.

I would like to automatically load data (from an external page PagB.cshtml) with JSON and display it on the page PagA.cshtml.

I tried this:

PagA.cstml (page of the request):

```
    <script>
$.ajax({

    url: 'PagB',
    async: false,
    global: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'TestA': Testa, 'TestB': testb },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var value = msg.data;
        alert(value);

    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("fail");

    }
});
```

```
<div>@TestA</div>
```

PAGB (page processing):

```
    @{
    Json.Write("TestA : 00000000", "TestB : 00000000", Response.Output);        
}
```

This Does not work. can you help me?

Comment: why do you try to get your data from a call to a cshtml file instead of a .json file?

Comment: Hi Serv! For me, maybe a .json file. But the question remains ... how?